# AngularJS with StreamSaver.js Support

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add the following [StreamSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js/blob/master/example.html#L137) code to an AngularJS. The same syntax is not accepted so I have changes the code to suite angular.

I got the following `WritableStream is not defined` error.

```
angular-1.5.7.min.js:117 ReferenceError: WritableStream is not defined
    at Object.createWriteStream (StreamSaver.js:92)
    at m.$scope.downloadFile (profile_ctrl.js:305)
```

The StreamSaver [Example code](https://jimmywarting.github.io/StreamSaver.js/example.html) is working fine.

```
fetch(url).then(res => {
    let reader = res.body.getReader()
    let pump = () => {
        return reader.read().then(({ value, done }) => {
            if (done) {
                myFile.close()
                return
            }
            myFile.write(value)
            return pump()
        })
    }
    pump()
})
```

Whereas not the modified code given below.

```
var myFile = streamSaver.createWriteStream("filename.txt");
fetch(url).then(function(res) {
    $scope.pump = function(reader) {
        return reader.read().then(function(value, done) {
            if (done) {
                myFile.close();
                return;
            }
            myFile.write(value);
            return pump();
        });
    };
    var reader = res.body.getReader();
    $scope.pump(reader);
});
```

Comment: Dose your targeted browser support ES6 syntax? StreamSaver only works in chrome and opera so my examples was written using the latest syntax. You might want to convert it down to ES5

Comment: I am getting this syntax error during code compilation. I have an angularjs website want to download files as streams. Chrome v52 is the browser I am using for testing.

Comment: what syntax error? do you want to use torrent? cuz you are missing interval variable

Comment: Hi @Endless, I have removed the torrent part and edited the question to reflect current error.

Comment: WritableStream should be defined in chrome v52, may i ask what version you are using?

Comment: Chrome 53.0.2785.57 beta-m (64-bit) Windows. I can access the example page and download a 10MB file. But not with the modified code.

Comment: I am using Chrome 53.0.2785.116 m and I get the same error, using the ES5 example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because of ES6 syntax. The following code works for ES5 in chrome v52 browser.

```
var myFile = streamSaver.createWriteStream("filename.txt");

fetch(url).then(function(res) {
  var reader = res.body.getReader();
  $scope.pump(reader);
});

$scope.pump = function(reader) {
  return reader.read().then(function(result) {
    if (result.done) {
      myFile.close();
      return;
    }
    myFile.write(result.value);
    return $scope.pump(reader);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You would better to use existing packages in angularjs. For example [angular-file-saver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver) trying to wrap FileSaver.JS.

Comment: filesaver.js has limits which is not good for large media files. Moreover in chrome for android, the maximum file size is amount of RAM available. So thats a major drawback of filesaver.js